# Is ZFS on Ubuntu 18.04 root supported?

Tags: 18.04, zfs, canonical

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with a root filesystem on ZFS without any problems but have discovered this page from the Ubuntu Wiki which states ZFS on root is not supported: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/ZFS

> ZFS support was added to Ubuntu Wily 15.10 as a technology preview and comes fully supported in Ubuntu Xenial 16.04. Note that ZFS is only supported on 64 bit architectures. Also note that ZFS is only supported for data storage, not the root filesystem.

Can anyone tell me if this is still relevant in Ubuntu 18.04? For example if I raised a paid for support request with Canonical would they be willing to help?
This blog post from Ubuntu suggests it's a valid configuration: https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/10/15/deploying-ubuntu-root-on-zfs-with-maas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported by Canonical. The [Ubuntu Wiki page on ZFS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZFS) says:

> In addition to be able to have ZFS on root, install:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install zfs-initramfs
> ```

The [`zfs-initramfs` package is in **universe**](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=zfs-initramfs) (for 16.04, 18.04 *and* 18.10), which means that it's maintained and supported by the community, not Canonical. If it ever gets promoted to `main`, [where `zfsutils-linux` is](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zfs-linux/+bug/1532198), then we can assume support.